# One point compactification. (Pushout)

Tags: general-topology

> I apologize in advance for the formatting. I am new to commutative diagrams in latex.
>
> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, with the pushout
>
> $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
> (V^{\infty}\times \{\infty\})\cup(\{\infty\}\times W^{\infty}) @>{}>> V^{\infty}\times W^{\infty}\\
> @VVV @VVV\\
> \{\infty\} @>{}>> Y
> \end{CD}
>
> Show that $(V\times W)^{\infty}$ is homeomorphic to Y
>
> Here $"\infty"$ denotes the 1-point compactification of a set

Previously, we proved a few remarks about pushouts.

If $X$ and $B$ are topological spaces and $A\subset B$ a closed subspace with inclusion function $\alpha:A\rightarrow B$, and continuous mapping $f:A\rightarrow X$.

We define the equivalence relation "$\sim$" on $X\coprod B$ as $inc_X\circ f(a)\sim inc_B\circ\alpha(a)$ for each $a\in A$. We thus define $Y:=(X\coprod Y)/\sim$ (quotient space).

It was shown (universal property of the pushout) that given a commuting diagram marked in the below picture of solid maps/arrows, there exists a unique mapping $g:Y\rightarrow W$, which makes the whole diagram commutative.

I want to somehow use this property (I think) to show there exists a homoemorphism $h$ from $Y$ to $(V\times W)^{\infty}$

I honestly have no clue how to approach this problem, and would appreciate a hint or two to guide me in the right direction. Any help would be much appreciated!

[Universal property of the pushout (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBmUp.jpg)

Comment: Pushouts are unique. So all you have to do is to show that you can use $(V\times W)^{\infty}$ instead of $Y$ to obtain pushout. If you can then they have to be isomorphic in the given category. In case of topological spaces it means homeomorphic.

Comment: Also this depends on what the upper arrow is. Is that inclusion? Note that this depends on the left arrow as well, but in this case there's no choice.

Comment: My apologies, the upper arrow is the inclusion map, the right arrow is the quotient map, the left arrow is the continuous function f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the catgorical definition of pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)). It is enough to show that $(V\times W)^\infty$ has the universal property. That's because pushouts are unique up to isomorphism.

I will use $V^\infty\vee W^\infty$, i.e. the wedge sum instead of $(V^\infty\times\{\infty\})\cup(\{\infty\}\times W^\infty)$ because thats what it is.

So we have a commutative diagram

$$\begin{CD}
V^{\infty}\vee W^{\infty} @>{i}>> V^{\infty}\times W^{\infty}\\
@VVV @VV{f}V\\
\{\infty\} @>{g}>> (V\times W)^\infty
\end{CD} $$

So $i$ is the inclusion, $g(\infty)=\infty$ and

$$f(v,w)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\infty &\text{if }v=\infty\text{ or }w=\infty \\ (v,w) &\text{otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$$

So this is the first part of the universal property. I encourage you to check that the diagram commutes and that $f$ is continuous.

Lets have a look at the second part of the universal property. Assume that 
$$\begin{CD}
V^{\infty}\vee W^{\infty} @>{i}>> V^{\infty}\times W^{\infty}\\
@VVV @VV{a}V\\
\{\infty\} @>{b}>> P
\end{CD} $$

is some commutative diagram. Define

$$\phi:(V\times W)^\infty\to P$$
$$\phi(v,w)=a(v,w)$$
$$\phi(\infty)=b(\infty)$$

So obviously $\phi\circ f=a$ and $\phi\circ g=b$. So all that is left is to show that $\phi$ is continuous. Can you complete the proof?

**Side note:** If you look carefuly at each function I've defined you will see that there's no magic here. These are just natural choices.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I just realized before you posted that I could swap $Y$ with $(V\times W)^{\infty}$ and show it satisfies the universal pushout property. This really helps, thanks for taking the time to answer!